# Wordpress custom menu for different categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

How do I get different menus for different categories? When we add a new category through the admin we want a custom menu to generate dynamically.

Comment: if the categories are top-level, there is a small tick box at the top of the menu admin that will "automatically add top level menus" otherwise you will need to do that manually or with a custom query in code ...

Comment: Hi CL75,
you have not understand me  completely. For example we go on a categorie  (dog) with  a sub categorie (food for dog) and the we should get a different menu for every sub categorie. For example in the categorie food for dog the menu can hold dog food but in other categorie (dog) with sub categorie (fur) so in there we shuold have a menu with the stuff for brushing the fur. The trick is how to have a custom menu (or something like it in the admin to be added to a specific sub categorie). Can it be done easy with wordpress or should i make it like a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made it. My conception was a play with the category - In example the category is with the name of the menu so we can make many categories and many menus. He are some of the links wich put me on this thoughts:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-menus-on-different-pages

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-menusheaders-for-different-categories

Comment: Could you please give additional details about your solution?
Which file should be edited?
Code snippet of what you added?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you mean simple , yes, it is possible and IMHO , simple .

You can not however, AFAIK ,  do that in the core WP UI.

what you basically need to do ,is create some menus , and then use conditionals, in specific [is_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category); in order to display them like so :

```
if( is_category( array( 9, 'food', 'bones' ) ){ // you can use either ID or slug...
        wp_nav_menu( 'a')
    } else if( is_category( array( 99, 'fur', 'flees' ) ) {
        wp_nav_menu('b')
    } else if( is_category( array( 'whatever' ) ) {
        wp_nav_menu('c')
    } else {
        wp_nav_menu('x')
    }
```

please look also at [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

Comment: @Benchik - in the same file where you have the menu ( typically in header , but not always, and not only. it really depends on your theme ). make a search and find the menu that you want to change ...

Comment: Benchik i want to make addition on Obmerk Kronen post. 

For example you want to have a menu in a category food so you place it in the food-category.php file from your theme.